# What can we do to reduce/eliminate the "follow up with hiring manager" questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, canonical-questions

Over the past few weeks, we receive the following question, or one of its variants, about 3 times per week. Each asker's circumstances vary slightly, but the question is essentially the same.

> I had a good interview 3 days ago. I have not heard from the hiring manager. Should I call them?

Then the following two things happen:

1. Someone replies asking OP to wait longer, and keep looking for other jobs in the meantime. (I have myself been "guilty" of doing this once.)
2. The question gets closed as duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6018/3192)

Is there something we can do to help new users get to the "solution" faster and reduce the unnecessary effort for the other community members?

In particular, note that when I try to ask the above question (in blockquote), the *Questions that may already have your answer* list has the above "canonical" question far below (currently at no. 15 for me), after a bunch of irrelevant questions. If there's some way to bump it up closer to the top, that might help.

Comment: They are all duplicates.  Close them as duplicates.  If they arent duplicates then leave them be.

Answer (score 5):

I think what Chad wrote in his comment is the best answer.

If it's a duplicate, close it as a duplicate. No harm in this - if it's a good duplicate then the asker gets the answers they are looking for.